# Adding LIMIT to query increases query time by over 1000%

Tags: mysql, limit

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT 
        MyField,
        COUNT(*) AS MyCount
    FROM
        MyTable
    NATURAL JOIN
        AnotherTable
    WHERE
        Timestamp >= 1000 AND Timestamp <= 10000
    GROUP BY
        MyField
    ORDER BY
        MyCount DESC;
```

This runs fine and takes about 6 seconds to complete. If I want to limit the result to show only the 20 highest `MyCount`s, I add `LIMIT 20` on to the end of the query. Suddenly it takes 6 minutes to complete!

The `EXPLAIN` output for the original query:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys             | key     | key_len | ref                       | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | MyTable     | ALL    | mytable_fkey              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                      | 6858209 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | AnotherTable| eq_ref | PRIMARY                   | PRIMARY | 4       | test.MyTable.FKeyID       |       1 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The `EXPLAIN` output for the query with `LIMIT 20`:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------+-------------------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys             | key                     | key_len | ref                       | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------+-------------------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | MyTable     | index  | mytable_fkey              | myfield_timestamp_index | 771     | NULL                      | 6858209 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | AnotherTable| eq_ref | PRIMARY                   | PRIMARY                 | 4       | test.MyTable.FKeyID       |       1 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------+-------------------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

What is the explanation for this? Is there a better way I can limit the number of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see `Using temporary; Using filesort` in your `EXPLAIN` output, you are probably missing a suitable index and you're getting killed because of it.

Make sure your `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` fields are both available in the same index.

Comment: He is ordering by `COUNT(*)` and he can't have an index on that.

Comment: @zerkms: There is a `NATURAL JOIN`. The join condition is hidden.

Comment: This doesn't explain how wanting to limit the result by 20 rows causes it to take over 10 times as long. Also, why doesn't it use the `myfield_timestamp_index` the first time?

Comment: Yeah, that `COUNT(*)` is going to be trouble. I saw the `ORDER BY` and thought that was a field, but it's an alias for a world of hurt. One crappy solution is to select into a temporary table, then fetch from that with a `LIMIT` clause from that.

Comment: @tadman Yeah, I tried doing that and it does work, I was just hoping for a better solution but it looks like I'm not going to get one. Oh well.

Comment: Could you try replacing the ORDER BY clause with ORDER BY NULL and add the LIMIT 20 on that query, in order to see if the sorting part causes the delay? This is extra weird though, as whether you use limit or not MySQL must fetch all records beforehand and sort them. LIMIT should have little impact on performance when sorting is used, it should only probably affect the stage when the server "pushes" data to the client buffer.